# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-toolbar-title issue vue3 and vuetify 3.0.0-alpha.0 version

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetify-loader

I am getting below issue while running the sample application with below configuration.

**package.json**

```
> "vue": "^3.0.0", 
> "vue-textarea-autosize": "^1.1.1", 
> "vuetify":"^3.0.0-alpha.0"
```

**Main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.css'
app.use(vuetify).use(VueTextareaAutosize)
```

Getting below warning and component is not visible.
Can anyone help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a warning and not an issue. Generally, you can sort it by importing the components correctly.

Also, you need to import vuetify correctly

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)
const vuetify = createVuetify(...) // Replaces new Vuetify(...)

app.use(vuetify)

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: It is just a warning, yes, but the vuetify components don't get rendered. I had the same problem because I didn't exactly follow the instructions on https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation

Comment: This comment is misleading.

Answer (score 8):

The answer above didn't help me. I had to use this:

```
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'

import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const app = createApp(App)
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})

app.use(vuetify)

app.mount('#app')
```

as described on https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#adding-vuetify