# How to resolve "Failed to resolve component: v-treeview"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

How to best resolve the warning: `Failed to resolve component: v-treeview`, which results in a failure to render the desired treeview component?

I've tried the top suggestions in answers here, including specifically importing the components and directives and passing them to `createVuetify` in both the plugin and main files, (also suggested in the "Getting Started" docs.)  I've tried turning off cache, downgrading vuetify, deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling, and some other things that either didn't work or broke everything.

Using

- `"vue": "^3.2.38"`
- `"vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.10"`

**src/plugins/veutify.js**
*(created by vite or vuecli)*

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify(

)
```

**src/main.js**
*(created by vite/vuecli)*

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import { loadFonts } from './plugins/webfontloader'

loadFonts()

createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .use(vuetify)
  .mount('#app')
```

**Fields.vue**
*(custom)*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-treeview :items="structure" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
...
// structure = [{name:'...',id:'...'},...]
const structure = ref([])
...
onMounted(async () => {
...
structure.value = await parseStructure(j)
}
...
```

Comment: Where do you set and define the data of "structure"?

Comment: @Geshode it's returned from a fetch call in `onmounted` and parsed/filtered (minimally).  I've amended the code above to reflect some of that.

Comment: vuetify 3 has NO v-treeview - it's one of the **many** components yet to be converted to "vuetify next"

Comment: @JaromandaX Whaaaa?  if true, possible drag  It's in the docs and the distro. Is there an alternative or workaround?

Comment: @JaromandaX dang -- it's NOT in the v3 docs--i was hoodwinked into the v2 docs.  ok. thx!  (It is in the distro tho)

Comment: `tried the top suggestions in answers here` - what suggestions did you try? since vuetify 3 does not have a v-treeview, I highly doubt anyone has a suggestion on how to make it work ... and yes ... it's true - the source for VTreeview hasn't been touched in the next branch ... as for workarounds ... search for a vue3 treeview and good luck - I have the same issue with VDatepicker for instance

Comment: Welll yeah...you're right.  I had tried the explicit import of components, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70719044/vue-warn-failed-to-resolve-component-v-toolbar-title-issue-vue3-and-vuetify)

Comment: How about using `<v-list>` as an alternative?